# Really bad amp distortion

Tags: amplifiers

I am having a really gross sounding distortion from my amp. It's a Peavy Solo Trans Tube IV. I've plugged in my acoustic and electric and I've tried several different cables but still the same problem. no over ride my low mid and high is all on 5 and it's still badly distorted

Comment: I think we need a lot more information - valve or solid state based, have you checked all your cables against a known good amplifier, etc.

Comment: It's a peavy solo trans tube iv tried several amp chords and all fail to solve the problem do you think it could be my outlets iv tried all around my house

Comment: Was it working correctly recently? Could it have been damaged? Have you made any changes to it lately?

Comment: The one thing you don't seem to have checked is whether the amp itself is faulty.

Comment: I would doubt it has anything to do with the power in the house.  If everything else seems to be operating fine, and different circuits all sound the same, I'd look more at the amplifier itself.

Answer (score 2):

A "gross" sounding distortion in a solid-state amplifier makes me think it's a speaker problem, since we can rule out any faulty tubes.

**Check your speaker** - use a flashlight, if possible to try and see if there's any visible tears through the open holes of the speaker, through the back of the amplifier (assuming it's an open-back design).  If that's not possible, you'll need a way to remove the speaker to see if there's anything that looks awry.